# issue with QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscrollarea

I am trying to add some check boxes in scroll area.but for me it is not working properly.i am new in python could anyone help?

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from configparser import ConfigParser
import paramiko
import threading
import os


if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.configur = ConfigParser() 
        self.configur.read('ServerConfigurationDetails.ini')
        self.serverName=self.configur.sections()
        print(self.serverName)
        self.getComponents = self.configur.options("Component")
        self.sLen = len(self.serverName)
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(951, 634)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 220, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 220, 231, 31))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 40, 101, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 260, 681, 81))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 201, 20))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 30, 201, 20))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox)
        self.checkBox.setEnabled(False)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 231, 31))
        self.checkBox.setChecked(True)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 30, 171, 20))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 40, 411, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 40, 131, 31))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 125, 661, 21))
        self.label_5.setText("")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 110, 681, 101))
        self.scrollArea.setAccessibleDescription("")
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 679, 99))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")

        c=10
        n=0
        x = 10
        y = 10
        print(self.sLen)
        for i in range(self.sLen):
            if(n==4):
                n=0
                x=10
                y=y+20
            self.checkbox1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.checkbox1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(x+1, y+1, 161, 20))
            self.checkbox1.setText(self.serverName[i])
            self.checkbox1.setObjectName(self.serverName[i])
            print(x)
            print(n)
            n=n+1
            if(n==4):
                x=10
                y = y+20
            else:
                x= x+180


##        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
##        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 161, 20))
##        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
##        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
##        self.checkBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 131, 20))
##        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
##        self.checkBox_4 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
##        self.checkBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 10, 151, 20))
##        self.checkBox_4.setObjectName("checkBox_4")
##        self.checkBox_5 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
##        self.checkBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 10, 141, 20))
##        self.checkBox_5.setObjectName("checkBox_5")
##        self.checkBox_6 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
##        self.checkBox_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 161, 20))
##        self.checkBox_6.setObjectName("checkBox_6")
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff) 
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.scrollArea_2 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 380, 681, 191))
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_2.setObjectName("scrollArea_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 679, 189))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.scrollArea_2.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 340, 811, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 951, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuhelp = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuhelp.setObjectName("menuhelp")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.actionAbout = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout.setObjectName("actionAbout")
        self.menuhelp.addAction(self.actionAbout)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuhelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Component</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "eComm"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "workproc"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Other Details"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Only Search in Archive"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Also Search in Archive"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto Download"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Only Search in Log"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Search String<span style=\" color:#ff0000;\">*</span></p></body></html>"))
##        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
##        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
##        self.checkBox_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
##        self.checkBox_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
##        self.checkBox_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))
        self.menuhelp.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))
        self.actionAbout.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

as you can see the scroll area is not showing properly.i have some 20 servers to show.this server list is coming from ini file and i need to show the check boxes in that scroll area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use QLayout to arrange you widgets. check out 
Qt Designer -> "Widget Box" docker -> "Layouts" section

For the scrollarea part:

1. create scrollarea `scroll_area = QScrollArea()`
2. create view widget you want to put inside scrollarea `base_widget = QWidget()`
3. install view layout for view widget `base_layout = QVBoxLayout(base_widget)`
4. install view widget into scrollarea `scroll_area.setWidget(base_widget)`
5. fill in objects with view layout `base_layout.addWidget(QLabel('foo'))` `base_layout.addWidget(QPushButton('bar'))` `base_layout.addLayout(my_sub_layout)` etc.